# PayPal buynow button setting issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to test my PayPal "buy now" button. It goes to sandbox page successfully and I do payment from my developer account. Problem is that my that payment do not go to my developer business account after paying with my developer personal account.

Here is my code:

```
    <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my-developer-business-id@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test product">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="some return url">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Please also tell me how can I make shipping option off... I don't need any shipping option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating button from sandbox account's website.

Steps to create PayPal button:

- Login to your seller's test account in sandbox.
- Click on 'Merchant Services' tab.
- There you will find Create PayPal payment button
- Fill out the form as per your requirement.

This will generate a HTML script.

Create a HTML file and copy paste this HTML script. Open the HTML file, You will get a Paypal Button.

Click it and accept transaction by buyers PayPal account.